# How to create a date-range-filter with a simple setup in Angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date

I have created a little StackBlitz-Project that represents my situation. I want to log all objects within a chosen date range.
But when I filter my object I get a empty array as results. I wanted to ask you how to compare dates, because depending on which datepicker you have you get a different value from the datepicker. It also depends on in which format you store the date (in this case a string).

Could you help me with my simple example?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbqguu

EDIT: 
I created an array:

```
  public obj = [{
    name: "jan",
    date: "20.03.2010"
  },{
    name: "ion",
    date: "10.01.2003"
  },{
    name: "caesar",
    date: "01.02.2009"    
  },{
    name: "chris",
    date: "17.03.2015"    
  }]
```

and I am trying to filter the objects with a certain date of the format 'DD.MM.YY' as you can see. Therefore I created to functions for two different inputs of type date.

```
<div>
  <p>Filtering by date range</p>
  <input type="date" (change)="changeFirstInput($event)"> - 
  <input type="date" (change)="changeSecondInput($event)">
  <span>
   <ul>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let o of obj">
    <li> {{o.name}} {{o.date}}</li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
  </span>
</div>
```

Filter functions

```
  public date1: Date = new Date("2000-01-01");
  public date2: Date = new Date();
  changeFirstInput(e){
    this.date1 = e.target.value;
    console.log(this.obj.filter(o => new Date(o.date) >= this.date1 &&
                                     new Date(o.date) <= this.date2  ));
  }
  changeSecondInput(e){
   this.date2 = e.target.value;
   console.log(this.obj.filter(o => new Date(o.date) >= this.date1 &&
                                     new Date(o.date) <= this.date2  ));
  }
```

My filter function returns an empty array `[]`. I am not really sure how to compare dates, I guess it depends on all formats you have as mentioned above.

Comment: It would be better if you provide some sample data in the question itself as text and format that you are getting from datepicker

Comment: I did! Thank you for mentioning it

Answer (score 1):

you can use date range filter from ngx-bootstrap and simply implement in your project.

1) This code insert datepicker liabrary in your angualar project so add this code in app.module file.

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
  ]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

2) This code insert in your app.componet.html file [HTML FILE].

```
<input type="text" placeholder="SELECT DATE" class="form-control" bsDaterangepicker (ngModelChange)="getByDate($event)"
                            [(ngModel)]="this.filters.date">
```

3) This code insert in your app.component.ts file [business logic]

```
    public filters = <any>{
        "to": '',
        "from": '',
      };

 public getByDate(event) {
    this.filters['from'] = event[0];
    this.filters['to'] = event[1];
    console.log(this.filters['from'],'===',this.filters['to'])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The date input will return date value as `2020-01-25`, you should convert both the date to proper date

```
console.log(this.obj.filter(o => new Date(o.date) >= new Date(this.date1) && new Date(o.date) <= new Date(this.date2)));
```

**EDIT**
Got it - The dot(.) separator date need to convert first to proper date (string) [Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235315/11719787)

```
pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;

console.log(this.obj.filter(o => new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern,'$3-$2-$1')) >= new Date(this.date1) && new Date(o.date.replace(this.pattern,'$3-$2-$1')) <= new Date(this.date2)  ));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still get back an empty array.